# Partial sums and convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be the series and ${S_n}$ its partial-sum sequence. Is it true that if $\lim S_{2n}$ exists and $\lim a_n=0$, the series is convergent? As a counterexample, I thought of the sequence where $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ when $n$ is even and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ is odd. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

$S_{2n+1}=S_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$ so $\lim S_{2n+1}$ also exists and equals $\lim S_{2n}$. Hence the series is necessarily convergent.